# laravel Retrieve each user's comment

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I want to retrieve the comments of each user in an article that I have already commented.

I have 3 tables : profiles, comments and journals.

below the code :

```
$posters =\DB::table('comments')
            ->select('comments.*', 'profiles.name')
            ->leftjoin('journals', 'comments.journal_id','=','journals.id')
            ->join('profiles', 'comments.profil_id','=','profiles.id')
            ->where('journals.profile_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->orwhere('comments.profil_id',Auth::user()->id)->where('comments.journal_id','=','journals.id')            
            ->get();
```

Comment: Is there a reason your not using Eloquent for this?

Comment: Why, do you think that easier?

Comment: "I want to retrieve the comments of each user in an article that I have already commented".. Unclear.. Post Sample Data and Expected Output

Comment: Yes, it will be much easier :) Do you have Eloquent models set up for these tables already?

Comment: yes I have the Eloquent models for 3 tables